# $4$ Independent Events, $3$ outcomes each

Tags: probability, combinations

I have four independent events, each with three possible outcomes.

Probabilities of each outcome:

A: $10\%$
B: $70\%$
C: $20\%$

How to calculate the probability of $2$ B's, $1$ A, and $1$ C? Or any other combination.

If one were to make a table of all outcome combinations, should the probabilities sum to $100\%$?

I had an answer, but they didn't add to $100\%$, so  I am checking with you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll address your main question first, then the sidenotes:

2B's 1A and 1C, you can have it in multiple ways, ABBC, BBAC, etc.

Of the 4 events you have to choose 2 to be B = $\binom{4}{2}$ ways
Of the remaining 2, you choose 1 to be and 1 to be C = 2 ways

So there are $\binom{4}{2} * 2 = 12 $ ways for this to happen, and the probability of a given combination is $0.1 * 0.7^2 * 0.2$ = 0.0098, making the total probability **12*0.0098 = 0.1176**

---

For the sidenotes:

There are $3^4 = 81$ possible outcomes (with unequal probability weights. e.g. AAAA is very unlikely compared to BBBB)

For each event you have 3 choices to make (A, B or C)

As there are 4 events, you have 3*3*3*3 = 81 possibilities and yes they will all sum to 100%

---

Note: I read your comment on an answer, and I'll try to explain why that listing is not correct:

> Thanks for that. I understand how you got 12, perhaps I didnt word the
>   question correctly, as I got 15 AAAA AAAB AAAC AABB AABC AACC ABBB
>   ABBC ABCC ACCC BBBB BBBC BBCC BCCC CCCC

You are not paying attention to the order of events, which is not right because AACC can happen in 6 ways, which makes it's probability the sum of the probabilities of:

ACAC
ACCA
CCAA
CAAC
AACC
CACA

The probability of each event is the same  0.1 * 0.2 * 0.1 * 0.2, so the total probability of your "AACC" event (ignoring order) will be 6*0.0004 = 0.0024

Comment: Thank you,  your last point was what I missing.

Comment: @eredd glad it helped you!

Answer (score 0):

This can be broken down into two problems:

Given 2 Bs, 1 A, and 1 C, in how many ways can I arrange these events?

This is equivalent to asking how many unique ways I can permute $ABBC$, which is equal to $\frac{4!}{2!1!1!}$ = 12.

Now that I have every orientation of $ABBC$, what's the chance that it happened in the first place? That's equal to $Pr = (0.1){(0.7)^2}(0.2) = 0.0098$

Multiplying these together, we get: $12 * 0.0098 = 0.1176$

Comment: Thanks for that. I understand how you got 12, perhaps I didnt word the question correctly, as I got 15 AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
AABB
AABC
AACC
ABBB
ABBC
ABCC
ACCC
BBBB
BBBC
BBCC
BCCC
CCCC